# Can I exclude a file in a git repo from branching?

Tags: git, gitignore, branching-and-merging

I have a file (specifically my .gitignore file) in the repo that I want to track and push to a central repository, so others will receive a copy when cloning the project.

But I want to exclude the file from being duplicated by branching. I want to have only one version stable in all branches, so when I change it in one, I don't have to commit and merge (or cherry-pick) this change to all other branches manually.

Is there a way to achieve this with git?

Comment: No. If you need to often change `.gitignore` you're probably doing something wrong. May be you need `.git/info/exclude` file?

Comment: My project changes over lifetime, getting new files and folders to ignore. What do you think am I doing wrong? ```.git/info/exclude``` can not be pushed to another repo, so changes don't reach other users.

Comment: But these new files and folders get added to some branch and so you only need to incorporate them in this branches' `.gitignore`. If then these additions are merged into others, the changes to  `.gitignore`will be merged as well.

Comment: Would you create an new version in your release/shipment branch, just because a .gitignore changed?

Comment: But that's the thing, the `.gitignore` in your release branch won't need to change unless *other* files in that branch also change (no point ignoring a file that doesn't exist).  Whatever merge operation brings new files to ignore would also merge in changes to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

As there are several valid answers posted as comment, I'll self-answer here giving credit to Users Alexey Ten, wonce and Darryl.

Setting a file as 'stable' or 'pinned' between branches is probably not possible.

But in the special case of wanting the .gitignore file to be stable, this is most likely a case of wrong workflow.

Files should be included in the .gitignore file when they are generated, which has to happen in one branch eventually. Other branches will then not have these new files hence no need for a modified .gitignore. 
Once other branches also get the new files via merge or rebase, they should also get the modified .gitignore.
Wanting to merge just the .gitignore file means you probably have added a file also present in another branch manually, which probably was bad practice as you should have created it with a merge from the original branch.

A notable exception to this rule is if you want the .gitignore file for a wildcard-rule you previously created in an other branch. Adding a new file matching the wildcard-rule but not necessarily being the same as the file in the original branch is possible.